# After sorting from external listing.csv file and insert result in txt file >>listing2.txt

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file

```batch
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=; tokens=1-5" %%i in ('type listing.csv') do (
  echo %%k | find "CNSHA" > nul
  if !errorlevel!==0 echo Searched_Value  "CNSHA" was found in %%i: %%j:%%k
)
pause
```

With file `listing.csv` I would like to save the search result to another file `listing2.txt`.
In which lines of code to be include in the code formula `>> listing2.txt` to save the result of the sort or similar?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have formatted your code but there it appears not to look correct, can you please edit it accordingly if it is wrong such that potential responders can do so.

Comment: Please avoid posting links to external resources. If their content is relevant for your question: put the content in your question. Otherwise don't bother posting the links at all.

Comment: Done - just removed  this links -thanks for guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot just use:

```dos
Find "CNSHA"<"listing.csv">"listing2.txt"
```

Comment: I will see where to append in code this line You mentioned. That is solution   but I will try extend with possible  more items from %%i- till %%z columns . Anyhow many thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can append to a file inside a loop like this:

```batch
for ... %%i in (...) do (
  echo something >> output.txt
  echo or other
)
```

The above will put only "something" lines in the output file while the "or other" lines are printed to the console.

You can also write the entire loop output to a file by putting the redirection operator outside the loop:

```batch
for ... %%i in (...) do (
  echo something
  echo or other
) >> output.txt
```

That will put both "something" and "or other" lines into the output file.

Note that when using the append redirection operator (`>>`) you need to truncate or remove an already existing file if you don't want to preserve content that was present prior to the loop:

```
type nul> output.txt
```

You can avoid this additional step by using the write redirection operator (`>`), but for that you need to put the whole loop in parentheses:

```batch
(for ... %%i in (...) do (
  echo something
  echo or other
)) > output.txt
```

BTW, you can also put redirection operators at the beginning of a line, and it's good practice to do so, because it avoids involuntarily adding trailing spaces to output lines:

```batch
for ... %%i in (...) do (
  >>output.txt echo something
  echo or other
)
```

or

```batch
>>output.txt for ... %%i in (...) do (
  echo something
  echo or other
)
```

Of course you can also mix the two approaches (redirecting inside and outside the loop), so you get some output in one file and the rest of the output in another:

```batch
>>output1.txt for ... %%i in (...) do (
  >>output2.txt echo something
  echo or other
)
```

If you want filtered records from the CSV as the output, you need to reconstruct the output lines, though:

```batch
>>output.csv echo %%~i;%%~j;%%~k
```

In your particular scenario it might be easier to just use `find` instead of working with a loop:

```batch
>output.csv (type input.csv | find ";CNSHA")
```

---

Since you also tagged your question [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) I'm going to throw in a PowerShell solution as well, just for good measure:

```bsh
$headers = 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
Import-Csv 'input.csv' -Delimiter ';' -Header $headers | Where-Object {
  $_.baz -eq 'CNSHA'
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

The above writes all records where the 3rd field has the value "CNSHA" to a new file. Remove the `-Header $headers` if your input CSV comes with headers. Change the `Export-Csv` statement to something like this if you don't want headers in the output:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content 'output.csv'
```

Comment: Very valuable suggestions from you. Tomorrow I will try to do the same but without the loop only find command. Thanks for your support and help

Comment: I like this explanation! +1 I just add that you may also redirect the output to different files in just one (more efficient) redirection outside the loop using several _standard handles_: `for ... %%i in (...) do (` & `echo something` & `>&2 echo or other` & `) >output1.txt 2>output2.txt`

Comment: You can redirect the entire loop only when you enclose it within parentheses: `(for %%I in (...) do (...)) > file.ext`

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: We could find other  way to simplify  task do not write to >>file.ext and direct result to monitor screen  and later  copy / paste all lines to any editor for futher task !.Are there any posibility  to do that when loop complete and all lines a are on screen- and we are not using  copy /paste by mouse/keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming a possible previous file listing2.txt should be overwritten:

```
@echo off
setlocal
(for /f "delims=; tokens=1-5" %%i in (
  'find /i "CNSHA" listing.csv'
 ) do echo Searched_Value  "CNSHA" was found in %%i: %%j:%%k
) >listing2.txt
pause
```

Otherwse double the `>` the redirection to `>>`

Comment: Thank you for modifications codu and help.
This last line)> listing2.txt /) >> listing2.txt which allows you to save the result (solution) could not be used without your modification. I used unnecessarily: line
if! errorlevel! == 0 echo Searched_Value "CNSHA" was found in %% and %% j %% k.- that could harm the record to the txt.
Thank you once  again and have a nice weekend.